# Что это значит 0x01 ?

Tags: c, c++

что значит это?

```
int code = 0;
code|=0x01;
```

Comment: если вас интересует 0x01, то это шестнадцатеричная форма записи числа 1. Префик 0x как раз указывает на то, что число записано в шестнадцатеричной системе. А про |= вам уже написали ниже

Comment: Извращенная форма записи

    int code = 1;

Comment: @avp для побитовых операций эти извращения могут быть оправданы - побитовые операции имхо так воспринимаются лучше

Comment: @DreamChild, понято же, что это шутка. Пример в вопросе-то, тоже наверное, из контекста выдран.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

с первой строкой проблем не должно быть. А вторая - это просто

```
code= code | 0x01;
```

То есть, обычное побитовое или.

`0x01` - это такая форма для записи шестнадцатеричных чисел. В данном случае это просто 1. `0xFF` - это уже 255.